# Error starting kafka server: " **Different application** unexpected at this time"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am following a quick start guide for getting kafka up and running.
I have zookeeper running but when I try to start kafka server with the following command:

`.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties`

I get the following error
`\Teradata\Client\16.20\bin\ was unexpected at this time.`

I cant even begin to understand how the two might be related.

***Any tip is appreciated. I am very much stuck....***

Answer (score 4):

In my case I needed to change the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, changing from `Program Files` to `Progra~1` and `Program Files (x86)` to `Progra~2`

[image]

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to Kafka or Zookeeper, but how they load the Java Home and classpath.

You need to fix your PATH variable in Windows settings to not contain any spaces

Answer (score 0):

looks like the kafka process needs all environment variables in the CLASSPATH to be present. I was getting the same error for Meld which I had deleted but CLASSPATH still have a reference to that.

Removing it from the CLASSPATH worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33467044)

Answer (score -2):

1. If you are using the Apache Kafka package structure as it is, then fix the path.it will be resolved automatically.
2. downloaded apache Kafka folder structure kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 ->bin->windows-> All *.bat files.
3. kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0->config-> all *.properties files 
   so to start zookeeper go to the kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 ->bin->windows->in window address bar type cmd and enter after that enter:

   `zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config/zookeeper.properties`
    o/p: zookeeper will start working
4. To start broker again go to the same folder
   kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 ->bin->windows->in window address bar type cmd and enter after that enter:

   `kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config/server.properties`
    
   o/p: broker will start working.

**Note:** you can update your own configuration using this properties file.like change in port etc..

```
I can't even begin to understand how the two might be related.<br/>
```

[image]

For more information, you can check the blog: [Role of Apache ZooKeeper in Kafka — Monitoring & Configuration](https://medium.com/@rinu.gour123/role-of-apache-zookeeper-in-kafka-monitoring-configuration-c5bd1a7e4226)

Comment: this does not even remotely answer the question...